# How do I execute my program without ./a.out command?

Tags: c, shell

I have written a c program. I want to pipe the program and I want to make it look meaningful. So instead of writing `./a.out` each time, I want to name it `changetext`. To achieve that, I compiled my program following way: `gcc -o changetext myprog.c`. To the best of my knowledge, this should replace the use of `./a.out` and `changetext` should do that instead. But I'm getting `command not found`. I am new to c and unix environment. Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Try `./changetext` instead.

Comment: And it works!Many thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to write `./`, put it in a directory that's in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I must admit that I never liked that. I think that if `changetext` is an executable and it is in the current directory, it should be callable by its name only. I still don't know why not.

Comment: I did.My a.out* and changetext* both are in the same directory as my c program.

Comment: @Rudy For a long-winded explanation that does contain some rationale behind why this is like it is: http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html.

Comment: @rubenvb: Thanks, I will read it right now.

Comment: @Rudy if you could just put it in the answer section I would very much like to accept it.

Comment: @SittingBull: done.

Comment: Imagine someone has put a command named `ls` in your current directory. Imagine it's a script that nukes your home directory. Now think about whether you *really* want `.` in your `$PATH`. (Admittedly putting `.` at the end of `$PATH` is less dangerous, but attackers can still take advantage of common typos.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in a comment, you can either put a dot slash (`./`) in front of the executable to run it

```
./changetext
```

Or you put in in a directory that is referenced in the PATH environment variable. A nice explanation of this safety feature can be found here (thanks to rubenvb):

http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html

It says that this is more or less to distinguish built-in commands from user-written commands with the same name. I am not convinced though. The shell could simply prefer built-in names to user-supplied ones, and look in the current directory as well as in the PATH.

But this is the *nix way.

Answer (score 1):

In order to compile and run a program such as your `changetext` with just the command `chanhetext`, you must put the binary in a directory listed in your PATH environment variable.  It is recommended that you put programs that you made for your own use in the `~/bin/` directory.  The command you would use to accomplish this would be the following, assuming `~/bin/` already exists:

```
gcc -o ~/bin/changetext myprog.c
```

If it does not exist, you can simply create it, then log out and back in.

Comment: No need to log out, you can just update your `$PATH` (assuming you know how).

Answer (score 1):

If you are tired of doing the ./ before the program name you can always make an alias such as
`alias a='./a.out'` or `alias changetext='./changetext'`
this just basically look for everytime you type `changetext or a` and then replaces it to have the `./` infront of it